# loading spring-{env}.properties in IntelliJ 2016.3

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot properties with three properties files:
[image]

I have a class that uses values defined in application-local.properties file, which I thought would get used because application-properties has `spring.profiles.active=local

When I start up in IntelliJ, I see this in the console logs:

```
Loaded config file 'file:.../build/resources/main/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
2016-12-18 20:10:17.596 DEBUG 29999 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:.../build/resources/main/application-local.properties' (classpath:/application-local.properties)`
Skipped (empty) config file 'file:...build/resources/main/application-local.properties' (classpath:/application-local.properties) for profile local
```

It says it skipped the empty config file, but when I inspect 'build/resources/main/application-local.properties' then I see the values in there.

However, the following class does not have the properties when I run it from within IntelliJ as a Spring Boot Application. It throws a null pointer because these are null:

```
@Value("${myapp.ApiKey}")
private String apiKey;

@Value("${myapp.ApiSecret}")
private String apiSecret;

@Value("${myapp.user}")
private String user;
```

In the Application Configuration I tried using Active Profiles, Program Arguments, and Environment Variables.

However, if I run from the command line as:

```
java -jar -Dspring.active.profiles=local  build/libs/myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

then it works just fine. I am sure this was working previously, but not sure if the IntelliJ version was the same.  Any tips on how to make the correct version of my application.properties get used?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Which spring boot version are you using? If you're using the latest this should be

`-Dspring.profiles.active=local`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles

Comment: I already added this to IntelliJ and it isn't picked up.  How do I get IntelliJ to view the right properties file?

Comment: Your question signifies the opposite. Firstly you've used the wrong flag,
`java -jar -Dspring.active.profiles=local` vs `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local`.
Secondly, I don't think you need to point Spring to your properties file as you've suffixed it with your profile's name, so Spring should pick that up automatically. 
If you're still curious how to do that though you can specify the location of the properties file with this flag `-Dspring.config.location=/path/to/file.properties`

Comment: So on your `application.properties` file you've set `spring.profiles.active=local`?

Comment: You were correct in that I had to old (?) flag.  But I wonder why I have to declare this at all - the application.properties file is getting loaded, but it doesn't point to the proper env file (application-local.properties) so those values are null unless I provide it via command line or IntelliJ env setting.  I also noticed that only one of my @Configuration classes actually get loaded.